# Android widget too small

Tags: android, android-widget

I hope I haven't missed another thread with the same topic, but I've been looking for a solutions for days.

I implemented an Android application which uses `android:minSdkVersion="10"` and `targetSdkVersion="17"`.

Inside this app I defined a widget with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:id="@+id/account_info_widget_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/appwidget_dark_bg_clickable"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:layout_margin="0dp"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:orientation="horizontal" 
              >
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_entry_padding_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_padding"
    android:background="@drawable/appwidget_divider" />

  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
  >
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_info_widget_btc"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_xlarge"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="#eee"
    />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/account_info_widget_balance"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_xlarge"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textColor="#eee"
    />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My widget xml file contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:initialLayout="@layout/account_info_widget_content"
                android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/cell_size_1"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/cell_size_3"
/>
```

`Cell_size_1` and `_3` are defined as 40dp/180dp for version 14 and 72dp/220dp for other versions as suggested in the documentation.
On Android less than version 14 everything looks fine, but Android 4 displays the widget flatter and narrower than all other widgets.

Now I found out that if I change target SDK version to 10, the widgets work on Android 4 too.
Is there a point I missed for the widget-definition or could you please give me a hint, what I should try?
Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: 1. When you use targetSDK = 10, you play by pre-ICS rules. For example, there's no automatic padding added by the system
// 2. Can you give us more information about your testing? Real device, emulator? Launchers?